# vsnprintf and strerror: segmentfault?

Tags: c

My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>

int test(const char *fmt, ...);


int main(void)
{
        int i;
        errno = ERANGE;
        const char *s = "test for vsnprintf";
        test("%d,%s", i, strerror(errno));
}

int test(const char *fmt, ...)
{
        char buf[512];
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, fmt);
        vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, args);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        va_end(args);
}
```

the above code throw out a segmentfault, but when I replace the `test("%d,%s", i, strerror(errno))` to `test("%d,%s", i, s)`, the program work well, What's wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the output of Valgrind?

Comment: Note that `i` is used without it being initialized, which results in undefined behaviour. It might break the program in unexpected way. It might not be reason for segfault, but should be fixed before going any further.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me on Mac OS.  Try running under valgrind and in a debugger to pinpoint the problem.  Note that you did forget to return a value from each of your two functions, and you'd be better off using `puts(buf)` instead of printf with %s.

Comment: If you use GCC, it optimizes printf("%s\n", *) using puts.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to read all warnings, and compile with -Wall -Wextra ^^.
You forgot to include "< string.h >" which contains the strerror header.
It should work with it ;).
Yeah, sometimes missing includes can really makes your code segfault.